# Is BIN bootsector is comptitable with GNU-Only ELF bootloader?

Tags: x86, gnu

Is BIN bootsector is comptitable with GNU-Only ELF bootloader?
I'm running VM with x86_64 CPU.
Requires these libraries:

- /lib/ld-linux.so

Comment: What kind of bootloader are you trying to make, exactly?  I don't think a dynamically-linked bootloader has any chance of working with the regular `/lib/ld-linux.so` in your main filesystem, because there's no OS to invoke it, and that file uses Linux system calls which aren't usable until Linux is already loaded + booted.

Comment: Running from bootsector.

Comment: No, i'm creating own bootloader named "DorianTech dBoot"